# c# Edit bindingsource with linq datasource

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have a binding source who's datasource is the result from a linq query. I have several controls bound to this binding source. When the value of the controls is changed, how would I go about saving the value against the binding source and eventually the db?

Thanks

EDIT:

So my bindingSource is lined to a datasource like the following:

```
this.jobBindingSource.DataSource = jobDao.JobByJobNumber(jobNumber);
```

The query backed by the dao is:

```
return (from job in this.GetTable<Job>()
                 where job.Job_Number == jobNumber
                 select job).First();
```

Comment: A. Providing some source code can be very helpful ...
B. You want the datasource to change when you change the value of it's control?

Answer (score 0):

LINQ queries usually return something that is readonly (if what the query returns still contains some context to the datasource this might be different - in that case there may be some way to **commit** changes made to an item)! You did not provide any details about what you are querying against, but this should also be the case for you.

Therefore you have to propagate changes to your data **manually** - manipulate the datasource you are querying against, at least changes can not be "written back up" through the LINQ query you bound the controls to.